# how to transform rows into list inside of a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two variables (Columns) that are related: one represent the name a person, the other count the times this person workout in a week. The problem is about visualize that data.

when i want to see the data it looks like this:

```
     x  name  wrk       
0    0   E    1  
1    1   A    2  
2    2   B    5  
3    3   A    3  
4    4   C    6
```

now, the letters are repeated the times that this pearson appears in the variable "wrk". then I just want to see that letter, but   without repetitions. For example when i want to see the mean of every person i see one letter and its mean on "wrk"

```
        wrk
name          
A    4.625000
B    5.142857
C    5.400000
D    3.833333
E    4.785714
```

I just want to see every value in wrk and only one letter in name, so I thought the solution is transforming wrk on a list to the output be like this:

```
               work
name          
A    1:2:3:5:7:8:10
B         1:2:4:7:8
C             1:6:9
D    1:2:3:5:7:8:10
E    1:2:3:5:7:8:10
```

the thing is I've shearched how to make this but i haven't found the code that helps me to do it. Can someone help me?

(sorry for my English, I'm learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
df['wrk'] = df['wrk'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby('name')[['wrk']].agg(':'.join)
```